# How to adapt to the formal parameter list of the 'use' function in Vue App?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, element-plus

As shown in the figure:

[image: screenshot]

From the prompt, ElementPlus seems to be a

```ts
{
  version: string;
  install: (
    app: App<any>,
    options?: Partial<ConfigProviderProps> | undefined,
  ) => void;
}
```

type, but how should this type adapt to the `plugin: Plugin<Options>` in the 'use' function?

Although 'ElementPlus as any' can solve the problem, it may not be a good solution.

I hope to describe the types of objects like "ElementPlus" correctly and use precise formats to adapt the formal parameter lists of different functions.

My project relevant dependences are:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.3.11",
    "element-plus": "^2.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^18.2.2",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.6",
    "@types/node": "^18.19.3",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.5.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.25"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus/issues/403

Comment: On the premise of being able to run and build, it is necessary to solve the error problem by using type ignoring. Does this mean that TypeScript still has legacy issues in this regard?

Comment: what legacy issues?  it'd be the fault of the library if it's not providing the right types, but it looks like that github issue was resolved a long time ago.  add relevant packages and version numbers to your question.